# Schengen Single entry Business Visa to Multi entry

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, netherlands, business-travel

I hold an Indian passport. I am invited by a company in Netherlands for an interview in April last week-May first week 2019. They provided a letter to be shown at embassy requesting Single entry Business visa. I will be applying for visa this week.

I also plan to go to UK and Netherlands again in June 2019 for tourism purpose. I plan to apply for UK visa in May 2019. I might not have enough time in May 2019 to apply for Schengen visa again as my passport will be with UK embassy.

Is it possible to request Netherlands embassy now to provide a multiple entry visa valid till June 2019 though company invitation letter says Single Entry business visa.

P.S. This is not the first time I am applying a Schengen visa. I have travelled to Schengen area in August-September 2018 and had applied Schengen visa through Netherlands Embassy at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can request a multiple entry visa. You should disclose all of your planned journeys in the visa application, so that the visa officers can evaluate your application properly.